# Images display only if article is on first page

Tags: image, joomla, joomla1.5

My Joomla 1.5 site was reinstalled after some problems. Since then, when I add images to an existing or new article, the new images display fine if the article appears on the first page, but not if the article is linked to a menu. The old pictures that were there before the reinstall are fine either way.

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Thnks !

Comment: This site relies on tags. Please add more that just "image" tag next time. You will get more help sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with relative / absolute paths.

The former i.e. images/something.png will fail when you have SEF urls turned on (so if your URL looks like http://yoursite.com/burning/vulcanoes, the relative path is interpreted as http://yoursite.com/burning/images/something.png instead of looking for the image at its location in the root.

Most likely you weren't using SEF on the previous host.  Joomla controls this through the SEF plugin (which you need to enable in the plugins administrator page).  Just enable the plugin, clear the cache and you should start seeing the images again.